# UnicodeEncodeError when writing asian characters to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I've been running into this error rather consistently when trying to write Asian-characters to a file - I can print the characters just fine in IDLE (though not in the command line) but when I try to write them to a file, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tai\Desktop\Development\playlistcreator\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    playlistcreator.addtoplaylist(list_of_paths,"C:\\Users\\Tai\\Desktop\\New Music\\testplaylist.m3u8")
  File "C:\Users\Tai\Desktop\Development\playlistcreator\playlistcreator.py", line 74, in addtoplaylist
    playlistFile.write(track + '\n')
  File "C:\Users\Tai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 56-57: character maps to <undefined>
```

I *think* understand what the error is: basically it can't render Asian characters so it can't write them to a file - but if I can print them in IDLE, why wouldn't it be able to write them to a file? Is there any way to get around this?

(I'm not sure if the code is necessary to understand the error, but I'll post it anyway)

```
def addtoplaylist(paths, playlist_path):
    # Open file (or create if it does not exist)
    #change to given directory
    try:
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(paths))
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
    #open file - if it does not exist, create it
    with open(os.path.basename(playlist_path), 'a+') as playlistFile:
        for track in paths:
            playlistFile.write(track + '\n')
    playlistFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding for your file when opening it, for example:

```
with open(os.path.basename(playlist_path), 'a+', encoding='UTF-8') as playlistFile:
```

Otherwise Python defaults to using your console encoding (ANSI) for files, in this case [CP 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which is the Windows name for extended Latin-1.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an encoding suitable for the characters.

```
playlistFile.write(track.encode(encoding=some_encoding) + '\n')
```

I guess `some_encode = 'utf-8'` will do but not really sure.

Maybe IDLE is using a different encoding by default and that's why it works there.

Comment: I tried it and got another error (albeit a different one): `playlistFile.write(track.encode(encoding="utf-8") + '\n')
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str`

Comment: I managed to fix it by making the string a byte-literal, but now I have the same error again with a different set of characters - I probably need to change the encoding again - but thanks for setting me on the right track!

Comment: @TaiM. you're using Python 3, this advice applies to Python 2 only

Comment: Reminder to myself: In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ah, I didn't know there was a difference in encoding between the two - fair enough!